# How to get currentTime with an Event Listener in vaadin app

Tags: java, dom-events, vaadin-flow

Vaadin doesn't have any out-of-the-box video component. So I created a custom class to serve as video component. Everything works well except that timeupdate event returns null as currentTime as the video plays.

```
@tag('video')
public class Video extends component implements clickNotifier{
public Video(){
getElement().addEventListener('timeupdate', event -> {     System.out.println(this.getProperty('currentTime'));
});

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First a word of warning: The `timeupdate` event is fired up to 60 times per second. It is not advisable to send updates to the server with that kind of frequency. You would probably have to implement some client-side logic to process the events and then occasionally send an aggregated update to the server.

For similar reasons, Flow is not eagerly synchronizing all changes to all DOM properties to the server. Instead, you need to instruct it to use some specific DOM event as a trigger to synchronize some specific property. The most convenient way of doing that is with the `Element::addPropertyChangeListener` overload that also accepts a DOM event name. Furthermore, you can use the return value from `addPropertyChangeListener` to further configure the listener to only send an update to the server if it's e.g. more than 1000ms since the last time an update was sent.

In your case, that could be like this:

```java
getElement().addPropertyChangeListener("currentTime", "timeupdate",
    event -> System.out.println(event.getValue()))
  .throttle(1000);
```

Comment: O @Leif, I'm super thankful to you. Your implementation returns the correct currentTime as video plays. However, it repeatedly pauses and plays it so that the playback is not smooth. Though happens fast, the pausing and playing troubles the they eyes. Any idea how it could stop the pausing and playing or at least make unnoticeable? Thank you ahead

Comment: I would guess your network connection is overwhelmed by handling up to 60 requests per second to the server only to update the millsecond part of the timestamp. This prevents it from loading video data quickly enough which in turn causes the video to pause while buffering. What you would need is thus some logic to skip events to send them e.g. only once per second.

Comment: I realized that there's even a bulit-in mechanism for throttling events. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: the mechanism didn't avail much. It's not stopping the repeating pause and play. However, many thanks for even investing time to help me move past this bottle neck in my project. I appreciate you greatly.

Comment: To buttress my attempt,  I even cranked up the throttle to 10k like so:.throttle(10000) and the pause-play thing persisted. For now , I suspect the glitch could be from my controller class where I configured Httpheaders.set('accept-ranges, 'bytes')...just so the video could allow seek. Anyway, again thank you so far, @Leif